# pop up window close

Tags: php, javascript

how to close the pop up window and focus to the main calling window of that pop up.

Comment: Do you want it , using Java script?

Comment: You'll have a tricky time doing that with PHP.

Comment: You can't do that with PHP alone, so I added Javascript to the tags.

Comment: what kind of pop up is it? Is it a browser window, or is it a DOM element/container? And if the latter, is it rendered dynamically, or is it a static container initially hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Using Java Script - 
Use it to close the popup window -

> window.close();

this is used to set focus on Parent Window -

> opener.focus(), or
>   window.opener.focus();